# Securing .Net Core Web Api for Angular 2

Tags: .net, security, authentication, angular, asp.net-core

I would like to build an application entirely in Angular2 which will do its talking with the database by sending calls to .Net Core Web Api. There are many good articles on building Web Api layer and my ng2 is alright, but I'm struggling to find material on how to secure the Web Api for my Angular 2 calls and potentially for third party calls. I'm opened for any security mechanisms (Oauth2 ?). Any guidance is appreciated.

Comment: Clone github source of MVC to get samples

Answer (score 0):

did you have a look at this Azure-Sample on GitHub?

https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-angularjs-singlepageapp-dotnet-webapi

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Securing a `WebApi` is usually done using OAuth2 (access_token).
To do so you need to implement your own OAuth2 token generator server or you can use the Identity Server 4 (using Identity Server will give you the SSO functionality).
On login the Angular app will receive an access token and send it in the header of every request to the `WebApi`, the `WebApi` will validate the access token and authorize the request (to do this the Identity Server already have a js library and a lot of samples on github).

Have a look at https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4

Answer (score 0):

You can secure the app using authentication and authorization on WebAPI. Like the other answers you can use the token based authentication.  You can find many online materials for this. One main thing when you secure an API, is to make sure the authorized user has access only to those resourses he has access to. I have noticed many developers ignoring this. Applying authentication and authorization is not enough but we need to make sure the authorized user is not able to access another user's data with same authority.